# Can't get Results of Ad in Business Manager through Marketing API

Tags: python, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk, facebook-business-manager

I use facebook business SDK to get data from facebook business manager by Python. I can get almost all fields using get_insights method, but I can't get Results field. And I don't see it in the documentation.

```
params_ads={'time_range': {'since': '2021-03-01', 'until': '2021-03-23'},'level': 'ad', 'limit': '20000'}
fields_ads = [AdsInsights.Field.account_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.account_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.adset_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.spend,
           AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
           AdsInsights.Field.clicks,
           AdsInsights.Field.outbound_clicks,
        ]

ads = my_account.get_insights(params=params_ads, fields=fields_ads)
```

Comment: What do you mean by Result field?

Comment: By Result field I mean the column in Ad Manager. Please check this image https://ibb.co/k88hcHt. I highlighted it with red color.

Answer (score 0):

The image is too low quality to be sure, but "Result" is a collective name in Ads Manager for the main metric based on the optimisation goal of the ad set. There is no such metric as result. Consequently, it cannot be retrieved.

However, what appears as value in this column, can.

Comment: Sorry, this one is better https://ibb.co/2SqQxc6. Do you have an idea how to get a number that appears in this column?

Answer (score 0):

The results field you are looking at, is not a "field" by itself, but instead shows what the campaign/ad set is primarily optimising for. This can be different depending on account / ad set settings.

In your case, it seems to be ThruPlays.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. I've found that I can get the results for different ad settings through action_type, but I still can't find out how I can get number of thruplays.

Comment: ThruPlays is kind of a special metric on Facebook. I found this page to help with the definition: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/471190536725647

It states that;
The number of times your video was played to completion, or for at least 15 seconds.

Which means that it is a calculated field, with some logic behind.